# How to change the function of a JFrame button?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm writing a program in NetBeans using `JFrame` that will use one button to connect and disconnect. When the client clicks the "Connect" button, an `ActionListener` creates a connection to the server. While connected, the button text changes from "Connect" to "Disconnect".

If the client clicks the button again, the connection needs to be closed. The specific commands I want to implement are `pw.close()`, `br.close()`, and `mySocket.close()`.

If for any reason the client loses connection to the server, the button text will change back to "Connect" and clicking the button needs to re-establish the connection. This is what I have so far:

```
private void connectBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       
        try {
        
        mySocket = new Socket(serverName.getText(), Integer.parseInt(port.getText())); //connect to server
        pw = new PrintWriter( mySocket.getOutputStream(), true ); //initialize printwriter
        br =  new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream() ) );//initialize buffered reader                  
        
        output.append("Connected to server\n");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {output.append("Connection Failed\n");
        }  
          
       if (mySocket.isConnected()){
            connectBtn.setText("Disconnect");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JCheckBox` or `JToggleButton` with a text of "Connected".

Check the [state](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()) of the box / button in the action listener to (`if` / `else`) take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

To make your JButton act as a toggle you **could** do something similar to this:

```
// Class member variable.
private static boolean connectedToServer = false;

private void connectBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String buttonCaption = connectBtn.getText(); 
    if (buttonCaption.equalsIgnoreCase("connect") && !connectedToServer) {
        /* A method to connect to server. Returns boolean true 
           if successful and boolean false if not successful. */
        connectedToServer = connectToServer();   
        if (connectedToServer) {
            connectBtn.setText("Disconnect");
            connectBtn.setBackground(Color.green);
            connectBtn.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
    }
    else if (buttonCaption.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnect") && connectedToServer) {
        /* A method to disconnect from server. Returns boolean false 
           if successful and boolean true if not successful.     */ 
        connectedToServer = disconnectFromServer();
        if (!connectedToServer) {
            connectBtn.setText("Connect");
            connectBtn.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            connectBtn.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.foreground"));
        }
    }
}
```